# Use ajax call for fill display table

Tags: jquery, ajax, displaytag

I'm working with portlets and spring MVC. I want to get a list of items with an ajax call and use that list as the display:table attribute.

I use this ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({ url:'<portlet:resourceURL id="recuperarDatosAF">
 </portlet:resourceURL>', data: {idExpediente:expediente}, type: 'POST',
  datatype:'json', success: function(data) { 
      alert(data); 
  }
```

This call is executed each time the user selects an item of a combo. the list of items that will be different each time recovered.

My question is: How could generate displaytable with that list I just get?

There a way to update a display: table defined in the jsp with that list?

The display that I have defined, retrieves the list of requestScope but I want to retrieve the list with ajax call.

My display:table:

```
       <display:table id="docentes" name="${requestScope.docentesList}"                       
                                           htmlId="resultadosDocentesListTable"
                                           pagesize="4"
                                           class="displayTagTable"
                                           uid="docente">
```

Comment: data is containing, html/json ?

Comment: ok I was a bit unclear, how does the returned json-object look like and how do you want it to be presented?
@Chipmunk0110 suggestion below seams to solve your described problem.

Comment: I was looking for a way to keep the format of the display: table but updating the list used to show with ajax.Do not know if that's possible

Comment: @user1821460 check my answer, it may b useful for your question

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kVdZG/

Script to generate a table from json data, replace alert(data) with this code, here data.scores is my data

```
var data = { "scores" : [ ["3/1/2011", 610],["4/1/2011", 610],["5/1/2011", 610],["6/1/2011", 610], ["7/1/2011", 720], ["8/1/2011", 500], ["9/1/2011", 500] ] }



$(data.scores).each(function(index, element){
         $('#scores').append('<tr><td> '+element[0]+' </td> <td> '+element[1]+' </td></tr>');       
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for answering
I already knew how to build a table by injecting the html code but wanted to know if you can generate a display:table or upgrade to a list obtained from the call. I use on jsp displaytag.

Answer (score 0):

**My question is: How could generate displaytable with that list I just get?**

From my experience, your list must contains Map of json data eg:

```
Map productMap = new HashMap();

    productMap.put("id", "1");
    productMap.put("name", "Coca Cola");                

    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    productList.add(productMap);

    jsonWriter.object()
        .key("status").value(true)                   
        .key("pList").value(productList)
        .endObject();
```

The pList is contains Map of product.

**There is a way to update a display: table defined in the jsp with that list?**

Yup, after I check the display table tag part using firebug, I have found out that the display table tag will be change to normal html table. So in **ajax**:

```
success: function(data){
    if(data.status == true){
        var strHtml='';                
        for(var i=0;i<data.pList.length;i++){
        strHtml+='<tr><td>'"+data.pList[i].name+"'</td></tr>';   
        }
    jQuery("table#docentes tbody").html(strHtml);
    }                   

},
```

and your **display tag**:

```
<display:table id="docentes" pagesize="4" class="displayTagTable" uid="docente">
    <display:column escapeXml="true" title="Product Name" >
    </display:column>                                                                                 
</display:table>
```

Comment: This only appends to table once display tag has already been generated, pagination is removed, which defeats the purpose of the display tag