# How to populate list data from server side to display tag using ajax in jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, displaytag

I am working on a leave approval table, where managers can approve or reject leave for this I am using display tag to populate the pending leave request.

```
<disp:column title="Reject">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="Reject"
          onclick="rejectLeave(this,${rows.id})" />
</disp:column>
```

onclick I am sending ajax request to approve the leave or reject leave. After updating the DB table, I am fetching the pendingleaverequest details again in the arrylist,  how do I pass this info to jsp to be displayed using displaytag.

```
<disp:table name="pendingLeaveRequest" id="rows">
          <disp:column></disp:column> 
</disp:table>
```

Will json accept array list or only Map?

Comment: are you using struts 1?

Comment: Nope. Actually I have replaced displaytag with JqGrid and things are fine.

Comment: Hi bro, i also facing same problem, but I have find out the solution by my self

Comment: Why dont you use, JqGrid instead of displaytag.  JqGrid is really good.

Comment: haha I have no idea about JqGrid

Comment: If you want to know how to populate list data from server side to display tag using ajax in jsp, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478570/load-json-data-in-display-tag-by-using-ajax

Comment: Or check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673559/use-ajax-call-for-fill-display-table/18480318#18480318